# How to restrict awk math output to 2 decimal places

Tags: linux, awk, cpu

My Command is below and its print Free CPU and Used CPU below format. 
I want to restrict awk output to 2 decimal place.

```
grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} {free=($5)*100/($2+$3+$4+$5)} END {print "Used Cpu:",usage "%"} {print "Free Cpu:",free "%"}'
```

Output :

```
Free Cpu: 98.9588%

Used Cpu: 1.04125%
```

Desired output :

```
Free Cpu: 98.95%

Used Cpu: 1.04%
```

Comment: use printf: `printf "Used Cpu: %.2f%%\n", usage`

Comment: Note, your END block only prints "Used Cpu" -- the block that prints "Free Cpu" is not in the END block, and wil therefore print for each line of input.

Comment: Hi Glenn,

I tried your suggestion and its work for me.

Edited command is below:


grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} {free=($5)*100/($2+$3+$4+$5)} {printf "Used Cpu: %.2f%%\n", usage} {printf "Free Cpu: %.2f%%\n", free}'

Used Cpu: 2.18%

Free Cpu: 97.82%

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to define an **output** format `OFMT="%5.2f%%"` to format **all** numeric output:

```
$ awk -v OFMT="%5.2f%%" '
         $1 == "cpu" {
                       print( "Used Cpu: ", 100*($2+$4)/($2+$4+$5) )
                       print( "Free Cpu: ", 100*$5/($2+$3+$4+$5) )
                     }
         ' /proc/stat


Used Cpu:   9.52%
Free Cpu:  90.48%
```

Comment: Hi Isaac,

Thanks for reply.
Can you please explain what is OFMT here.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Thanks Isaac its working with print in awk.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of code review:

- awk can do what grep does, so you don't need the pipeline
- add newlines to the awk code for reability

For example:

```
awk '$1 == "cpu" {
  printf "Used Cpu: %5.2f%%\n", 100*($2+$4)/($2+$4+$5)
  printf "Free Cpu: %5.2f%%\n", 100*$5/($2+$3+$4+$5)
}' /proc/stat
```

which outputs the nicely aligned

```
Used Cpu:  5.34%
Free Cpu: 94.63%
```

Comment: Is it possible to print output like below.


Used Cpu;Free Cpu


5.34%;94.63%

Comment: Of course. Just modify the print statements.